# Scala ide not picking latest code changes

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-spark, ide

In Scala ide, when I change my code and run the class, it's not taking latest code. Instead It runs old code only. Please provide any solution

Comment: [Maybe you wanted to report a bug?](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Bug_Reporting). Notice that this answer wouldn't count as a proper bug report either, because it lacks any kind of precise information. What's your scala ide version? What's your jre and scalac version? What's your OS? What's the code for which something doesn't work? What is your build system, and what does your build configuration look like? How do you know that it's the IDE and not your code?

Comment: ...did you try "Build -> clean"?